# ¿es correcto editar una pregunta solo para embellecer su código?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Me ha pasado más de una vez en preguntas de primerizos (y no tanto), donde veo códigos horriblemente indentados o con líneas de código haciendo tender el scroll horizontal al infinito y mas allá.
Por lo tanto, para tener una mejor comprensión del código, suelo copiar el código, aplicar algún linter localmente (usualmente `eslint`, integrado en mi editor, para código `js`/`jsx`) y luego editar la pregunta pegando el código en cuestión.
Ahora me entra la duda si en realidad es una práctica generalizada, si pueda prestarse para confusión del OP al no encontrar su código original o siquiera si representa una ayuda para quienes puedan ayudar al OP con sus consultas,
¿existe alguna pauta respecto a esto?

Comment: Menos para python (pues la identacion es importante para la pregunta), para todo el resto es mas que adecuado.. es mas.. el otro dia idente una pregunta de sql, y el error salto solito al mostrarle el codigo identado al usuario.

Comment: Tampoco es cuestión de embellecer, sino de mejorar la legibilidad del código (una buena práctica de código limpio) para todos.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Daré mi opinión.

Me parece una acción adecuada, considerando lo siguiente:

- No alteras el código en su esencia (no quitas ni modificas declaración de variables, métodos, clases, etc)
- Ayudas no solo al OP sino también al resto de la comunidad a facilitar la lectura del mismo
- Probablemente donde mas se visualice la ayuda es desde dispositivos móviles, pues un código bien indentado es mas fácil de leer y analizar para encontrar posibles errores

Los anteriores argumentos los menciono por que en ocasiones el OP, desconoce como usar las herramientas del editor de texto o puede ser que aunque le de formato a su script llega a omitir algunas partes y el código al final luce incompleto.

No lo considero adecuado cuando:

- Se llegasen a eliminar fragmentos de código
- Se cambien los nombres de variables/clases/métodos, etc basándonos en algún criterio personal.

Fin de mi opinión

Recordemos además que tenemos un [privilegio de 2000 pts. de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) que nos permite hacer ediciones de preguntas y respuestas donde dice y cito:

Algunas razones comunes para editar son:

- para corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía
- para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla
- para corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la * * publicación envejece
- para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados

Mientras que con una reputación menor a esa cantidad podemos hacer ediciones, las cuales entran en la cola de **Ediciones Sugeridas** que serán aprobadas o rechazadas por la comunidad de acuerdo a las pautas anteriormente mencionadas.

Así que en resumidas cuentas sí es algo que se debe hacer, respetando las reglas

Comment: De acuerdo con todo. Añadiría que es importante identificar cuándo es relevante dejar el indentado / los espacios que puso el OP. Por ejemplo, en lenguajes sensibles al indentado como Python. En general, es necesario hacerlo con cuidado para no quitar un posible origen del problema que reportan