# Ediciones rechazadas por usuarios que usan la edición bajo su nombre

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, convenciones-sociales

En varias ocasiones me he encontrado preguntas o respuestas con una ortografía, gramática o cohesión pésimas, independientemente de si las preguntas o las respuestas en cuestión aportan valor o no. De hecho, me he topado con más de una buena pregunta mal formulada o con (muchos) errores lingüísticos.

Con esto en mente, en muchas ocasiones edito publicaciones para corregir estos defectos. Pero ya me he encontrado en varias ocasiones con que algún usuario rechaza mi edición para editarla él mismo y presentar otra edición sospechosamente parecida a la que yo hice.

Personalmente, no soporto ver preguntas con una ortografía tan nefasta (si son pocos errores me da igual). Y la verdad, este tipo de situaciones me desaniman de editar publicaciones para mejorar su calidad.

¿Es correcto lo que estos usuarios hacen? ¿Tiene alguna importancia la corrección lingüística de las publicaciones? Dedico mucho tiempo a intentar ayudar (editando y respondiendo), y en muchas ocasiones el sitio parece más una lucha por conseguir puntos, que un sitio para ayudar a los demás.

En concreto, me refiero a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394771/c%c3%b3mo-sabe-c-si-una-funci%c3%b3n-existe-y-adem%c3%a1s-d%c3%b3nde-est%c3%a1-ubicada/394778#394778), en la que hice [esta sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/235067) de edición, y [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/394778/4) fue la edición que hizo el usuario que rechazó la mía, la cuarta en el [historial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/394778/revisions) de revisiones de la respuesta.

Quizá sea pura casualidad, y quizá me esté quejando por nada, pero no es la primera vez que me pasa.

Comment: Tu edición era muy buena y es una pena que se rechazara. No parece, además, un caso de colisión de revisiones, sino rechazo plano para hacer sus propios cambios. ¿Has probado a hacerle un ping al usuario que la rechazó por si te puede dar más información?

Comment: A la hora de aprobar revisiones hay varias opciones disponibles para el revisor. Entre ellas, tenemos `Rechazar y Editar` y `Mejorar edición`.

En este caso, un revisor eligió (incorrectamente en mi opinión) `Rechazar y Editar`, cuando tu sugerencia de edición era buena. En todo caso, si pensaba que podía añadir alguna mejora a tu sugerencia, podría haber usado el botón `Mejorar edición`. De todas maneras, dentro de poco tendrás el privilegio de editar sin que deba ser aprobado y no tendrás estos problemas, no te desanimes :)

Comment: Es una pena que se haya rechazado. Tu edición es muy buena; salvo que se te pasó **irlas colocando** debía cambiar por **ir colocándolas** o **llevándolas a** el verbo ir no admite ese uso porque opera como auxiliar y el pronombre reflexivo **las** debe situarse en el verbo principal **colocar**. Este error en mi país es de uso común y solemos pasarlo por alto. Respecto a tu queja, seguirá ocurriendo, a muchos nos cuesta aceptar la evidencia de nuestros errores; aunque algunos lo tomamos mejor que otros.

Comment: Hombre, se que no va con la pregunta, pero queria decirte algo y por aqui no hay dm. Aprovechando que sugeriste la edicion a mi respuesta, queria darte las gracias. En realidad fallo mucho con la ortografia, sobre todo colocando las tildes. Asi que queria darte las gracias por ese apoyo increible que das, sigue asi amigo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Respecto a la lucha de puntos, no te desanimes: Ya estás cerca de los 2000 puntos de reputación necesarios para que tus ediciones no necesiten revisión (y dejarán de darte puntos, pero creo que eso es irrelevante).

Tienes razón en que a veces algunos usuarios intentan ganar puntos fácilmente haciendo ediciones triviales o innecesarias, o "apropiándose" de las ediciones de otros usuarios, pero no es algo mayoritario y al menos yo intento desalentar estos comportamiento rechazando ediciones de ese tipo o mejorándolas en caso de que se hayan dejado mejoras por hacer *por las prisas*.

En resumen: sigue aportando y no pierdas la ilusión.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Answer (score 7):

Me gustaría responder algo que no responden las otras respuestas:

> ¿Tiene alguna importancia la corrección lingüística de las publicaciones?

### Sí.

Toda corrección, a cualquier tipo de publicación (pregunta,respuesta) es buena, mientras mejore la publicación. Si la edición hace que la publicación sea más fácil de leer, entender, con una ortografía correcta, o cualquier otro tipo de mejora, La edición tiene importancia.

Edita siempre que pienses que la publicación puede mejorar, de alguna o otra manera, también mejorará al sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh ok vale explico el porque del rechazo y me disculpo si asesine una corrección tuya.

**Claro que la edición era buena**, lo que pasa es que hay algo que normalmente veo que algunos realizan y talvez no me tomé la molestia de preguntar en su momento.

Veo que muchos cambian el formato del código fuente original y la cambian a la forma que piensan que esta bien, el formato de código fuente en mi opinión es algo que prefiero no tocar, en mis inicios yo también realizaba esta acción pero vi que siempre que tocaba el código fuente mi corrección era rechazada, imaginaba que esto no era permitido y como antes dije *no me tomé la molestia de preguntar sobre este tema*.

Aclaro el porque tu pregunta fue rechazada y me disculpo nuevamente, es probable que también la acción correcta hubiera sido la de mejorar la edición y no rechazarla (OJO que en realidad buscamos la mejora del sitio, en mi caso el rechazo y mi edición no fue por los puntos ya que a partir de los 2000 no se me asigna ninguno por edición), te animo a seguir con tus correcciones y tendré en cuenta lo que se comenta acerca de las ediciones buenas (incluyendo el formato de código).

Saludos. ;)

Comment: me encanta el concepto de _asesinar_ una corrección :D ¡Sangre, queremos sangre!

Comment: En cuanto al asesinato en sí, a mí me funciona lo siguiente: si un % grande de lo que se está cambiando me gusta y una parte pequeña no, aprieto en "mejorar edición" y allí recupero lo que veo incorrecto. Creo que podría haber funcionado en este caso.

Comment: Saludos @fedorqui, tienes mucha razón es posible que en ese momento no tomé en cuenta algunos factores. Agradezco cualquier comentario constructivo ya que así podemos ir mejorando. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM entiendo que conforme pasa el tiempo uno cambia de parecer sobre las cosas. Personalmente sí que modifico el formato del código de una pregunta o respuesta para arreglar problemas serios, sobre todo los que tienen que ver con la indentación, para que se adapten mejor al sitio, y teniendo en cuenta que la pregunta o respuesta pueda servir a otras personas. Es muy común encontrar código con una indentación excesivamente grande (porque han sido cortados y pegados), o con mezcla de tabuladores y espacios.

Comment: Agradezco que hayas dado una explicación al rechazo de la edición. Y es comprensible si lo consideras que es modificar el código original.

Comment: Exacto, es muy común encontrar código con mala indentación, pero como mencionaba yo en su momento las arreglaba y mis correcciones siempre o casi siempre eran rechazadas. De todas formas tomaré en cuenta lo dicho en este post y agradezco que me lo hayas hecho notar. ;)

Comment: Esta publicación está interesante: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4317/193460