# Copiar el código desde el comentario de un autor a su pregunta

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Hace poco vi que el autor de una pregunta había dejado su código en un comentario y decidí copiarlo en la pregunta como sugerencia de edición. Fue rechazada, y los 2 que la rechazaron dejaron un comentario similar: que el autor de la pregunta tenía que hacerlo

> Para reducir un poco el espectro, en el caso al que me refiero, desde cola de revisión se le pidió que agregara código, y el autor lo hizo como respuesta a eso en un comentario, el cual copié y pegué -Sí, realmente copié y pegué sin modificar el código original y sin perjudicar el código original ni la pregunta. No quiero entrar en un caso en particular poniendo acá el link (no importa qué pregunta, ni quiero hablar sobre los usuarios que rechazaron). Esto va sobre el caso general en el que la intención del autor es aportar su propio código y simplemente lo hace en el lugar equivocado.

Me pregunto:

1. si esto es algo consensuado,
2. si hay algún motivo para que no convenga hacerlo, y
3. asumiendo que la respuesta va por algo similar a "*el usuario tiene que preguntar bien*", ¿realmente es tan importante que siga todos los pasos alguien que ni siquiera los conoce antes de que pueda encontrar una respuesta acá?

Desde mi punto de vista, es mejorar la pregunta. Además, muchas veces me parece que los usuarios nuevos no ven la opción para editar, o están acostumbrados a otras páginas en las que no se puede editar. Yo por ejemplo aprendí así, cuando vi que alguien editó mi pregunta... Así es como lo veo, por eso quería contrastar con la opinión del resto.

(seguramente ya haya otra publicación sobre esto y termine duplicada. Está bien si es así, realmente no pude encontrarla)

Comment: Ignoro si existe o no una regla escrita. Pero, presumo que exista un consenso tácito al respecto. La recomendación dice que nos debemos limitar a hacer modificaciones ortográficas y eventualmente sintácticas (gramaticales) para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta y ayudar con el **formato del código** sin alterarlo. Lo demás **es intocable**. En cuanto a pasar código del comentario a la pregunta: se ignoran el contexto y la ubicación de modo que altera el conjunto y puede malograr la pregunta. En consecuencia se solicita al OP que lo haga.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario!! En cuanto al contexto: desde cola de revisión se le pidió que agregue y lo hizo en comentario (no quiero entrar en detalles de **una** publicación, sino ver el caso general -ahora edito)... En cuanto a lo demás intocable, también leí cosas como: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4317/193460, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4858/193460, o https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1989/193460, con las cuales creo que estoy más de acuerdo.

Comment: Por cierto, si se trata de un consenso tácito aceptado por la mayoría, también me sirve como respuesta. Quiero confirmar si es así, entender los motivos que llevan a eso y a lo sumo discutir si es lo mejor.

Comment: Dije **presumo**, porque no he leído que no se pueda. Pero, el código que se pone en comentarios **es ligero** normalmente tiene propósito indicativo y adolece de falta de contexto de modo que **sólo el OP** tiene información suficiente para llevarlo dentro de la pregunta **sin provocar** desastres. De allí que a la gran mayoría no se nos ocurra moverlo y si se tienen privilegios (yo no los tengo) se *anule* la edición en que se haga.

Comment: Ahora entendí tu punto... No lo había considerado :-)

Comment: @quevedo. "sólo el OP tiene información suficiente" es una afirmación cuestionable. La mayoría de las preguntas son de absolutos novatos (en sus propias palabras) bien perdidos en el tema.

Comment: tu edicion nos llevo a consultar en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=55757285#55757285)

Comment: @CandidMoe Si fuera lícito suponer sin error que el contexto en el que está situada la pieza de código es correcto, no habría problema. **Pero** cabe esperar que allí puedan estar los errores o problemas que motivan la pregunta. De modo que **un usuario experimentado no los va a cometer** y desvirtúa antes que ayudar a clarificar.

Comment: El editor de código es deficiente. Malito, para ser honesto. Hay distintas alternativas para formatear código: Ctrl-K, el botón "{}", las triples comillas, el indentado, cada una con su caprichosa idiosincracia e inesperados resultados. No me extraña que los usuarios nuevos tengan problemas para editar el código; yo también pase por eso hasta que descubri que Ctrl-K es lo único que funciona con certeza.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Mi opinión

- **No se debería hacer**,

  por la sencilla razón de que **es responsabilidad del autor formular una pregunta correctamente**, lo cual incluye todas las ediciones necesarias después de la publicación inicial.
- **Es admisible**

  que un usuario se tome la molestia de copiar desde un comentario hacia la pregunta. No es una acción reprobable, puesto que la edición colabora a mejorar la pregunta en sí. No considero que sea necesario *revertir* ni *rechazar* esa edición.
- **No es recomendable**,

  puesto que se *malacostumbra* al autor. Es su responsabilidad, no de la comunidad.
- **Es un requisito**

  dejar un comentario al autor, del tipo

> Hola. He añadido el código a tu pregunta, porque **todos los detalles deberían estar en la propia pregunta**. Te he hecho un *favor* considerando que eres un usuario nuevo. Por favor, consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

- **Solo para usuarios nuevos**,

  que no suelen conocer como funcionamos y tienden a considerar SOes como un *foro* cualquiera.
- **Es inadmisible**

  en publicaciones de usuarios con cierta veterania. **Personalmente** tengo mi *nota de corte* en los 150 puntos. A partir de ahí, considero que el usuario ya está habituado a las normas del sitio. Si el usuario entra en esta categoría, voto negativo sin piedad y, opcionalmente, dejo un comentario.

Comment: Me hiciste pensar en que no dejé un comentario y que debería haberlo hecho. Creo que también podría invitarlo a aceptar la edición (que sino pueden pasar varias horas hasta que se vea). Muy de acuerdo con tu punto de vista.

Comment: "puesto que se malacostumbra al autor." No aplica. La mayoría de los usuarios sólo hacen una pregunta y desaparecen. Por otra parte, la mayoría del código publicado es de tan baja calidad que es imposible "hacerle daño" formateandolo y/o copiando desde comentario a la pregunta; de hecho se hace un favor a la Humanidad.

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo primero, no lo puedes saber *a priori*. Lo segundo es distinto. Una cosa es *aumentar el código de la pregunta* y otra formatear el código ya existente. Lo tercero ... totalmente de acuerdo :-)

Comment: De todas formas, es solo **mi opinión** y el *protocolo* que **yo** suelo seguir.

Comment: @Trauma. Tu respuesta me parece equilibrada y razonable. Desde ya la adopto como guía personal.

Comment: @CandidMoe Me siento halagado. Yo creo eso, que está mas o menos equilibrada. No obstante, intento evitar hacerlo yo y suelo dejar un comentario al autor para que se pase por el centro de ayuda, invitándolo a que sea él el que edite. Solo *copy/pasteo* en contadas ocasiones, cuando estimo la pregunta como **muy interesante** o **muy atrayente**. Vamos, que se pueden contar con los dedos de una oreja :-)

Comment: *puesto que se malacostumbra al autor* **Totalmente de acuerdo**, muchos que luego siguen usando el sitio, nunca terminan corrigiendo esa conducta.

Answer (score 6):

**Importante**: hablamos (al menos yo) únicamente a aquellas preguntas con "potencial" de ser un buen contenido para el sitio

> ¿Es válido copiar el código desde el comentario de un autor a su
> pregunta?

Se podría extender tu pregunta, a cualquier información adicional que agregue el usuario como comentario y que debería ser una edición. En mi opinión **es válido hacerlo siempre que el resultado realmente mejore la pregunta** y en particular en el caso del código en sí, no se trate de lenguajes como Python, dónde la identación es importante y es problemático volver a reproducirla desde un comentario. También, hay que decirlo, es válido, por que el sistema lo permite, claro que, estás expuesto al escrutinio de la comunidad que puede aceptar o no dicha edición.

Los principales reparos con respecto a esto que te han dado Trauma y Gbianchi, tienen que ver con desincentivar ciertos comportamientos de los usuarios, lamentablemente muy comunes, en usuarios nuevos y no tan nuevos. La idea subyacente es que si uno le hace las cosas fáciles a un usuario este nunca va a aprender, lo cual suena razonable, pero tengo mis dudas al respecto: Mi padre me decía *"Se enseña más con el ejemplo que con la palabra"* y me pregunto, ¿se enseña mejor diciendo al AP como debería hacer la edición de su pregunta que directamente haciéndola? yo, al menos, no tengo una respuesta ni tampoco he podido observar el funcionamiento de una estrategia u otra. De cualquier manera, coincido totalmente que la pregunta debiera ser responsabilidad absoluta del autor.

Te cuento un poco mi experiencia y criterios

- Si hay un dato importante que pueda ser trasladado al cuerpo de la pregunta, en general lo hago.
- En algunas pocas oportunidades puedo llegar a tener en cuenta la reputación del usuario, pero en general no.
- Soy pragmático, si es más económico, rápido y útil agregar un comentario como edición, lo hago.
- Con el código, prefiero sí, pedir en todo caso al AP que edite su pregunta, salvo que sean piezas muy pequeñas, más que nada por un tema práctico, me ha pasado intentar transcribir el código de un comentario y darme cuenta que está incompleto.
- Eventualmente, si detecto comportamientos repetitivos de un usuario, es dónde sin duda, evitaré mejorar su pregunta y aplicaré la didáctica, por medio de una sugerencia de edición.
- Esto casi nunca lo cumplo, pero creo que es fundamental: agregar una descripción de por que se está haciendo la edición.

Por último: Me gusta la idea de Trauma de dejar un mensaje al usuario, cuando uno edita su pregunta, trataré de implementarla.

Comment: Buen punto el de los lenguajes que usan indentación para bloques de código. Comparto 100% esa dicotomía entre desincentivar comportamientos y enseñar con el ejemplo, con el objetivo de mejorar la pregunta

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con lo que dices y con la enseñanza de tu padre. A veces una buena edición enseña más que muchos comentarios explicándole al usuario cómo hacerla.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a agregar algo a la excelente respuesta de Trauma..

Se de que pregunta hablas, y yo fui el segundo que rechazo dicha edicion.

En este caso, se hace para que el usuario aprenda. Tu edicion fue buenisima, pero dejaba directamente otra pregunta que no tenia nada que ver con la original, que hasta incluia una imagen.

Una de las cosas que tiene que aprender quien pregunta, ademas de lo que pregunta, es como preguntar... Si no, tenemos el efecto adverso.. Escribo lo que quiero, total despues alguien viene y me lo arregla...

Para colmo, este caso es peor, ya que quien pregunto, ni siquiera se tomo la molestia de leer los consejos que le dejamos, acepto una respuesta que le soluciono el ejercicio completo, y siguio de largo.

Por eso, yo (personalmente) estoy en contra de este tipo de arreglos, y siempre le enseño a los usuarios a editar sus posts.. inclusive cuando se la respuesta... porque aprender a usar el sitio es tan importante como la respuesta. Cuando tengan la proxima duda, la van a poder solventar mas rapido...

Y cuando vemos preguntas realmente interesantes, las arreglamos entre todos, de eso nunca quedan dudas.

Comment: Y agradezco que me hayas dejado un motivo que me ayudó a entender de qué se trataba (que quede claro, no estoy molesto por un simple rechazo, es lógico viendo los diferentes argumentos). -Tal cual, esa pregunta no fue por el mejor camino, por eso también no quise ponerla como ejemplo, sino simplemente abstraerme y discutir el caso general, también buscando lo mismo que mencionás: enseñarle a los usuarios.